# Some of the aliases you requested do not exist: events.create

Tags: facebook, events, sdk

i am trying to create new event using graph api.i set create_event permission for testing user. now i execute graph api but it gives me error like :

{
   "error": {
      "message": "(#803) Some of the aliases you requested do not exist: events.create",
      "type": "OAuthException"
   }
}

can anyone tell me why this happening.

Comment: We are not clairvoyant.  Please post code here to see what you are POSTing to the Graph.

Answer (score 1):

You are using an old method for creating events.  The `event.create` has been deprecated. As you can see from the [documentation](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/rest/) :

> **We are in the process of deprecating the REST API**. If you are building
>   a new Facebook application, please use the Graph API. While there is
>   still functionality that we have not ported over yet, the Graph API is
>   the center of Facebook Platform moving forward and where all new
>   features will be found.

Please read the [new documentation](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/event/) on events to learn about the new methods of dealing with them.

---

*We as facebook developers are solely responsible for keeping up-to-date with the changes that 3rd party API's, on which we base our development, make to their systems.
A great place to keep updated on changes **and** new features would be the [Facebook Developers Blog](https://developers.facebook.com/blog/) and the [Facebook Developers Roadmap](https://developers.facebook.com/roadmap/).*

Answer (score 0):

What is your Post URL ?

You need to Post to /events and supply at least the name and start_time parameters.
Note the start_time is strict about format, if the format is off, you will get a event id but the event is never created.

You can test this directly in [Graph API explorer](https://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer).