# Post to page at any time (offline access)

Tags: facebook-php-sdk, offline, whmcs

I'm trying to make a app that integrates into the WHMCS that will allows admins to set posts that will be put on their FB page's wall at a certain time.

I am using a piece of code that allows me to post to the page ok but when trying to run the PHP script from a CLI (Shell):

```
root@golf [~]# php -q /home/host/public_html/modules/addons/social/cron.php
```

I receive the following message:

> Please check Facebook API settings, OAuthException: (#803) Some of the
>   aliases you requested do not exist: 0

Could someone please tell me what this message means and how I can get this working.

Also if I have not access the app from the web interface for a while the following message is displayed:

> Exception: 102: parameters uid or session key required

A popup then appears on that page and it refreshes, the message is no longer there (until I come back a little later)

Would be great for as much help as I can get.

Daniel Collins.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8982749/some-of-the-aliases-you-requested-do-not-exist-events-create might be relevant to the error you are receiving.

Comment: You may need to note that 'offline_access' is deprecated and may be completly removed anytime. use tokens with extended expiry. - https://developers.facebook.com/roadmap/offline-access-removal/

Comment: Can someone confirm that the "Page Access Tokens" do not expire?

Comment: @DanielCollins, where did you get that from? I've never read it. Any official Facebook document?

Comment: "By using a long-lived user access token, querying the [User ID]/accounts endpoint will now provide page access tokens that do not expire for pages that a user manages."